# Linux: How to list all messages sent from sendmail

Tags: linux, logging, exim

I am getting occasional claims that people are not receiving some automated emails from the Apache server, which uses sendmail as the MTA.  How do I see a list of activity?  /var/log/maillog is empty.

CentOS 6.3

Answer (score 0):

I found it at `/var/log/exim/main.log`  Just in case anyone else wants to know the answer.

Comment: I think it's fairly clear that you were wrong about it using sendmail as the MTA, then!

Comment: I removed the sendmail flag from the post.  BTW, sendmail the binary is provided as a command line compatibility wrapper by any SMTP server that runs on linux as a sendmail replacement. And that is why the OP thought he was running sendmail instead of exim.

Comment: It's not so much the flag, more the OP's line "which uses sendmail as the MTA" that's wrong!  I'm not trying to make the OP feel bad about this, but it's awfully hard to diagnose problems when people state as fact something that is not, as it turns out, true.

Comment: Sorry, I used `alternatives --display MTA` to find out what the MTA was and it stated Sendmail.